# ffmpeg command to place a video stream on bottom left corner and another video stream in the center

Tags: video, ffmpeg, media, video-processing, mediastream

I am working on a server side solution to the problem of arranging 2 video streams in a way such that one of them is at the bottom left corner and another one in the center.
I found that ffmpeg is capable of solving this problem. However I am new to ffmpeg syntax and semantics and have tried some horizontal &vertical stacking as well as looked into padding, scaling.

```
Input - 2 webm files

Output - 1 webm file
```

This is a sample of the output I want to achieve:

[image]

In this sample, center portion is the main video stream and in the bottom left we have the other video stream playing side by side.

Assume that both the video streams are in sync.

I have tried experimenting with this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.webm -i input2.webm -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2  -c:v libvpx split1.webm
```

The above command stacks the two videos horizontally.

Although, I am experimenting more and more to get to the solution, thanks in advance as I am hoping there are developers sitting out there who have experience with ffmpeg.

Comment: There's an "overlay" filter FWIW...

Answer (score 2):

I assume `input1` is the main video and has resolution W x H and is without black bars baked in. `input2` has resolution w x h (possibly after scaling).

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input1.webm -i input2.webm -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw:ih+2*h:0:h[main];[main][1:v]overlay=x=0:y=H-h[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2  -c:v libvpx split1.webm
```

Comment: i get this error Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]pad=iw:ih+2*h:0:h[main];[main][1:v]overlay=x=0:y=H-h[v]; [0:a][1:a]amerge[a] matches no streams.